# Matplotlib figure does not update after a Line2D object is deleted?

Tags: python, matplotlib

After I draw a line, the program waits for 2 seconds. Then I delete this line with ax.lines.pop(0). After that I refresh the figure and the line should be gone? (I wait for two seconds again) But why does this not work?

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

# draw line
ax.plot([0.5, 0.7], [0.5, 0.8])

plt.pause(2)

# delete line
ax.lines.pop(0)

# update figure
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.canvas.flush_events()

plt.pause(2)
```

Comment: What is your environment (e.g. Jupyter, console, other IDE)? If you're in Jupyter with inline plots this won't work. You need to run `%matplotlib qt` once in the notebook to enable interactive plots. Restart the kernel or `%matplotlib inline` to go back to inline. The code works without issue in interactive mode.

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code. How can I get it to work there?

Comment: look up inline for interactive plots in VS code

Comment: Ended up using Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: I think it's easiest. For python, I prefer PyCharm over VS Code as a full-blown IDE